# Find the closest vector to an other in 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the vector $x$ in $S$ which is the closest in the 2-norm to the vector $c=[1,1,1,1]^T$.

I have a projection matrix that looks like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}

I have calculated this projection matrix via the formula $AA^T$ Where $A = [a_1, a_2]$ and $a_1 = [1,0,1,1]^T$ and $a_2 = [1,-1,0,-1]^T$. $a_1$ and $a_2$ constructs a subspace $M$ of $R^4$.

and we say that $Px \in M$ and $x-Px \in S$.

Here is what i have done so far:

Suppose that $x$ is in $S$ so $x = y-Py$. $x$ is close to $c$ in 2-norm means the minimum of $||(y-Py)-c ||^2 $(Am i right?). That is $yc^T - Pyc^T$ by applying $P$ and $c$ we would have $-2y_1 -2y_3 -3y_4$. This term must be minimum inorder to find the closest vector to $c$. But I dont know if my solution works or not.

Comment: Are you sure that the matrix you wrote is the correct matrix? An orthogonal projection matrix should be symmetric.

Comment: You must have, because an orthogonal projection matrix should be symmetric and the trace of the matrix should be the dimension of the space you are projecting on (in your case the trace is 5 while the dimension is 2). These are good sanity checks to apply when calculating a projection matrix.

Comment: The formula works only if the basis you use for the subspace is orthonormal and this is not your situation. You should perform Gram-Schmidt on $a_1,a_2$ and use the resulting basis to build $AA^T$.

Comment: @levap I have updated my vectors so now $a_1$ and $a_2$ are orthogonal, But yet again the trace of the projection is not 2.

Comment: And yet again you have an error - your vectors are orthogonal but not orthonormal.